# Python Plot yyplot scientific notation not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scientific-notation

I have the code running properly, producing a plot but I don't see the scientific notation. Don't know why?

code:

```
fig,ax1 =  plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x,y,'-',color=yclr)
ax1.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x,yy,'-',color=yyclr)
ax2.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y')
plt.show()
```

Plot:
[image]

Update:
Based on the accepted answer, I just included `scilimits=(0,0)` and it worked. But scientific limit font size is higher than rest, which were set to 12.

[image]

Comment: The left y-axis may have too limited a range for scientific notation to be displayed. The right axis may have a multiplier notated somewhere, but part of the axis notation has fallen off: use `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.show()` to try and correct that.

Comment: @9769953 It did not work. Gave the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `scilimits=(0, 0)` to `ticklabel_format` should trigger it.

```py
fig,ax1 =  plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x,y,'-',color=yclr)
ax1.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0, 0))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x,yy,'-',color=yyclr)
ax2.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0, 0))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I updated my question with latest plot. However, I see the scientific limit text displayed at a different font size. Any guess, how to correct it?

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the styles you applied to the axes. I'm not able to reproduce the behavior. You might want to consider opening a new question.

Comment: I am in full surprise. Executed same code in Google colab and produced no issues as I raised above. Any how thanks.

Comment: No problem. Just out of curiosity, what matplotlib version is Google Colab using? I tested it on 3.5.1.

Comment: I am new to colab and I have no idea. However, you know what, It started working flawlessly on my PC after deleting some `rcparams` I defined at the top.